# git push failed via personal access token authentication in android studio

Tags: git, android-studio, github, git-bash

I tried reading several solves regarding ssh server key but couldn't grab the idea. This is my first push to git repository so I will ask to keep the solution as simple as possible.

First I tried git push directly from Android Studio VCS. But having 2-factor authentication enabled it didn't work and showed error like authentication failed.

Then I generated Personal Access Token and add origin like this-

```
git remote -v 
git remote remove origin 
git remote add origin git@github.com:user/repo.git
```

Now while trying to git push, it tried to connect with SSH server key but failed.

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/
https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/

Comment: Having 2-step verification active in GitHub account create difficulties signing in through Android Studio. I deactivated that and it's working fine.

Comment: this is not really an android studio issue. It is more about 2-factor auth and that is the point of 2-factor to make it more secure (some might say difficult)

Answer (score 5):

Had the same issue when pushing from Android Studio with two-factor-verification enabled. As stated [here](https://help.github.com/articles/providing-your-2fa-authentication-code/) I generated a personal access token. This is described in more detail [here](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/). In essence you need to:

1. Go to your GitHub settings.
2. Click Personal access tokens (down to the bottom).
3. Generate a new Access token with the scope "public_repo"
4. Save the generated public access token in a password manager of your choice
5. Enter the personal access token when prompted for the password (!) by Android studio.

Comment: "For the password(!) part was the key for me"!